# Get Changes at runtime from XML file in java

Tags: java, multithreading, connection-pooling

I am managing socket connections in java , by reading "config" file. I want to create some concurrent thread that check it file is changed ? , and if it is then add/update host and port into connection pool.

Following is XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<config>
    <host>
        <hostname>localhost</hostname>
        <port>8087</port>
    </host>
</config>
```

Method to get Hosts from config file

```
public List<Host> getConfigHosts() {
        try {
            List<Host> list = new LinkedList<Host>();
            String cfgPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + this.DEFAULT_FILE;
            if (!this.configFileExist(cfgPath)) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid config file");
            }
            File config = new File(cfgPath);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(config);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            if (!isValidDocument(doc)) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid document type.");
            }
            NodeList hostNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("host");
            for (int i = 0; i < hostNodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Node n = hostNodes.item(i);
                if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element ele = (Element) n;
                    String hostname = ele.getElementsByTagName("hostname").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String portSt = ele.getElementsByTagName("port").item(0).getTextContent();
                    int port = Integer.parseInt(portSt);
                    Host h = new Host(hostname, port);
                    list.add(h);
                }
            }
            return list;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // No File Found, returning default values
            List<Host> list = new LinkedList<Host>();
            list.add(new Host(this.DEFAULT_HOST, this.DEFAULT_PORT));
            return list;
        }
    }
```